# Changing assembly version during pre-build event

Tags: visual-studio

I have a tool, a simple console app, that updates the version of my project when a release build is ran. It updates the csproj with the new custom version. I call this from a pre build event.

It updates the file correctly but after the build is done the version is the same as it was before the tool runs. Then on the next build it is set to what the first one should have been.

For example,  if the build is 1.0.0.0 and my tool were to update it to 1.0.0.1, the first build would output 1.0.0.0. Then on the second build it would change the csproj yo 1.0.0.2 but the output dll would be 1.0.0.1.

That is a simple example and not what the versions actually are of course.

My question is this: is the pre build event too late to update the version?

Comment: Other than downvoting can someone leave a comment as to why the question is not appropriate?

Comment: Set up a CI server and configure version bumping there. Rarely people do that on their workstation.